# Convert anonymous function in PHP 5.3 into PHP 5.2 equivalent

Tags: php, closures, anonymous

I have error in line 2 and 13 in PHP 5.2, I have no idea to make the correction, I tried using create_function but not working, can anyone help with this?

```
function _process_special_keyword($str){
   $callback = function($match){
     $ret = $match[1] . '[' . $match[2] . ']';
     if(!empty($match[3])){
       $ret .= '.[' . $match[3] . ']';
     } 
     $ret .= $match[4];
     return $ret;           
   };

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/([\s\(\.,])(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . ')(?:\.(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . '))?([\s\)\.,])/i', $callback, $str);

   $callback = function($match){
     return 'CASE WHEN ' . $match[1] . ' THEN ' . $match[2] . ' ELSE ' . $match[3] . ' END';
   };

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/if\s*\((.+),(.+),(.+)\)/i', $callback, $strSQL);
   return $strSQL;
}
```

Thanks.

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: ups, sorry missed that, here is the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the callbacks outside of this function.  Like this:

```
function _callback_one($match){
  $ret = $match[1] . '[' . $match[2] . ']';
  if(!empty($match[3])){
    $ret .= '.[' . $match[3] . ']';
  } 
  $ret .= $match[4];
  return $ret;           
}

function _callback_two($match){
  return 'CASE WHEN ' . $match[1] . ' THEN ' . $match[2] . ' ELSE ' . $match[3] . ' END';
}

function _process_special_keyword($str){
   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/([\s\(\.,])(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . ')(?:\.(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . '))?([\s\)\.,])/i', '_callback_one', $str);

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/if\s*\((.+),(.+),(.+)\)/i', '_callback_two', $strSQL);
   return $strSQL;
}
```

Note: If these functions are in a class (meaning the function would be need to called like `$this->_callback_one`), pass an array as the "callback" parameter.

```
function _process_special_keyword($str){
   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/([\s\(\.,])(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . ')(?:\.(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . '))?([\s\)\.,])/i', array($this, '_callback_one'), $str);

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/if\s*\((.+),(.+),(.+)\)/i', array($this, '_callback_two'), $strSQL);
   return $strSQL;
}
```

Comment: moving it outside is okay assuming it isn't a closure

Comment: @newacct: Pretty sure PHP 5.2 can't do closures anyway.

Answer (score 4):

When using `create_function()`, the contents of the first argument should be a string representation of the PHP code that would fill the parentheses for the `function` declaration. The second argument should contain only the code inside the curly braces `{}` of the function declaration, the actual declaration itself should be omitted.

Try this code:

```
function _process_special_keyword($str){

   $callback = create_function(
     '$match',
     '
       $ret = $match[1] . "[" . $match[2] . "]";
       if(!empty($match[3])){
         $ret .= ".[" . $match[3] . "]";
       } 
       $ret .= $match[4];
       return $ret;
     '
   );

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/([\s\(\.,])(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . ')(?:\.(' . SPECIAL_KEYWORDS . '))?([\s\)\.,])/i', $callback, $str);

   $callback = create_function(
     '$match',
     'return "CASE WHEN " . $match[1] . " THEN " . $match[2] . " ELSE " . $match[3] . " END";'
   );

   $strSQL = preg_replace_callback('/if\s*\((.+),(.+),(.+)\)/i', $callback, $strSQL);
   return $strSQL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according with object question, the faster way I think is something like so,

```
$f = <<<myfunc
 \$ret = \$match[1] . '[' . \$match[2] . ']';
 if(!empty(\$match[3])){
   \$ret .= '.[' . \$match[3] . ']';
 } 
 \$ret .= \$match[4];
 return \$ret;           
myfunc;

$callback = create_function('$match',$f);
```

note backslashes before $ and <<< FLAG FLAG; construct. In practice the answer of Rocket is more simple.

Comment: Use Nowdocs (`<<<'myfunc'`) to avoid having to escape the `$`s ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom: You can't use "nowdoc" syntax in PHP 5.2.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: @Rocket You know, I just realised that and came back here to say so but you beat me to it!